# Network Manager user-side dispatcher scripts

Tags: networkmanager

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13963/call-script-after-connecting-to-a-wireless-network) gives a solution to run scripts when a connection has been set up by NetworkManager. However, I'd like to run my script (that auto-connect to some special kinds of hotspot) as a non-root user, because it's quite dirty, and I would not bet that it's not possible to do code-injection inside. Do you know if a kind of `~/.config/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` exists ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing and here is what I did to make this work:

Create `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-user-scripts`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
#   Run NeworkManager dispatcher scripts from user home directories
#   for logged in users
#   See: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html
#   See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405242
#
for user in $(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq); do
  scripts_dir="/home/${user}/.config/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d"
  [ ! -d "$scripts_dir" ] && continue
  find $scripts_dir -type f -executable -user $user -perm -u+rwx ! -perm /go+w ! -perm /+s | \
    sort | \
    xargs -I{} sudo -u $user --set-home --preserve-env -- {} $1 $2
done
```

Set proper permissions on file according to [NetworkManager documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html):

```bsh
$ chmod u+x,go-w,a-s /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-user-scripts
```

Then create your user script directory and create your user script:

```bsh
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d
$ touch ~/.config/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/50-my-script
$ chmod u+x,go-w,a-s ~/.config/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/50-my-script
```

Here is a sample `~/.config/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/50-my-script`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
prog="$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
logger -t $prog -p user.notice "Running ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} $@"
printenv | logger -t $prog -p user.notice # verify environment variables are inherited
```

You can verify the sample script is being run by checking the system log after a network event has occurred.

## Limitations

- Will not work with `/root` or non-standard user home directory paths (easily fixable)
- For simplicity I chose not to implement the pre-up.d and pre-down.d functionality (a possible enhancement)
- I am not positive the execution order is exactly the same as `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` scripts. The docs say alphabetical, so I used `sort` on the found files. Probably not a huge issue but FYI.
- I am using Bash 4+ syntax rather than generic shell code because that is what I am familiar with. I imagine this could be made to support other shells.
- I make NO CLAIMS as to the security of this implementation!

Comment: Interesting trick, thanks!